# WPF - Why window suddenly loses focus?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, focus

## Scenario

Consider the scenario:
You start an application in WPF.

1. Main window opens (non-modally) `Window1` (owned by `MainWindow`)
2. You change focus to some other window (say, Visual Studio)

   - With other application having focus, you press on a button in `Window1`
   - Window1 shows a messagebox
3. You close the messagebox

Effect: your main window suddenly goes below window you chose in second step.

## Images:

### Step 1

[image: Step 1]

### Step 2

[image: Step 2]

### Step 3

[image: Step 3]

### Step 4

[image: Step 4]

## Sources:

### MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBox />
            <Button Content="Open window" Click="Button_Click" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

### MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Window1 window1 = new Window1();
            window1.Owner = this;

            window1.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

### Window1.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window1" Height="450" Width="800" ShowInTaskbar="False">
    <Grid>
        <Button Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

### Window1.xaml.cs

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Test");

            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

## Question

How to keep focus in the main window after closing the messagebox from the other window?

Comment: Your old window will lose control when you open the new form, as intended, however: Before you close that old window you would need to do something like `Form1.Current.Focus();`. You have to pass the instance of Form1 to the child form. So create a property on the preview form that you set before you call show. Then access that instance of the main form from the instance of the preview form

Comment: I updated my comment.

Comment: @Joel It looks like this works. Just an uptade, since `Window1` is owned by `MainWindow`, it's enough to call `this.Owner.Focus()`.

Comment: Do you want me to submit it as an answer?

Comment: What happens if you use [MessageBox.Show](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.messagebox.show) overload with owner?